# Prove that a topological space which satisfies the following conditions has base composed of clopen sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'll start with the definition I know:

> Let $X$ be a topological space. We say that $\text{dim}X\leq n$ if for every closed set $F\subseteq X$ with continuous function $f:F\to S^n$, there exists a continuous extension for $f$ over $X$, i.e $ \tilde{f}:X\to S^{n} $ continuous, such that $\tilde{f}\restriction_{F}=f$.

Now, let $X$ be a sperable metric space. How can I prove that $ \text{dim}X\leq0 $ $\iff $ $X$ has a base which composed of clopen sets (both open and closed)?

I'm not sure how to start any of the directions, so any hints/guidance would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\implies$ $S^0$ is just the two points $1, -1$. Take any $x \in X$, and $x \in U$ where $U$ is nbhd of $X$. $\{x\} \cup X \setminus U$ is closed, and define $f$ to be $1$ on $x$ and $-1$ on $X \setminus U$. This is continuous so extend $\tilde f$ on $X$. But $\{1\}$ is also open, which means that $x \in \tilde f^{-1}(\{1\}) = : V$ which is a clopen set and it is easy to see that we must have $V \cap X \setminus U = \emptyset \implies V \subseteq U$. So for every $x$ and a nbhd $U$ around $x$ we have found a clopen set $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$. So we have a clopen neighborhood.

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't expand, but - for the other direction. Use the fact that a function that is defined on a union of locally finite closed sets, and is continuous on the restriction to each of these closed sets, is continuous overall. We thus need to find said family of locally finite closed sets (that cover $X$), but we can do one better and make this disjoint- the first set will be $F$ and the rest will be disjoint clopen sets that cover $X \setminus F$. Thanks to second countability/separability you will get $F$ and a countable series of disjoint clopen sets covering $X$.